# Rails Routes vs URL parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, routes

I have a double headed question I hope you're able to help me with.

As a bit of context, I have a rails app with a Request model/controller/view setup.  It is used for a user to send a request to another user and provides two specific facilities within the update action (trying to stay RESTful) - accept and decline (accept or decline the request).

So my questions are:

- First, what is the generally accepted approach setting up the url for accessing a specific type of action (in this case accept or decline are both request updates)?  Is it better to pass it using a parameter (e.g. `/requests/11?response=accept`) or to use named routes (e.g. `/requests/11/accept`)
- Secondly, if using named routes, how can you determine which named route was responsible for calling the controller?  I think you can use `request.url()` or something similar to check the actual url (e.g. `/requests/11/accept`) but that seems to be a brittle approach to me.  I've tried to find other possible ways to do this but can't seem to find a decent way.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer /requests/11/accept to /requests/11?response=accept.

Accept and decline are behaviors that will change the state of request resource, so a PUT operation on a single object is appropriate.

You can define a route in your routes config, like below:

```
resources :requests do
  member {put :accept, :decline}
end
```

You will get two routes

```
accept_request maps to {:action=>"accept", :controller=>"requests"}
decline_request maps to {:action=>"decline", :controller=>"requests"}
```

Comment: To add to your answer, I consider anything that is a action/verb probably belongs in a route (IMO what the RESTful ideals were intended for). Where as anything that is a variable/adjective ie. `page=2` or `gender=male` is probably a query string (although once again common ones are usually routes too.)